# The browser is not opened Visual Studio C# Selenium

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

Although I have no errors, the Browser does not open when I want to run the tests

I want to run an older project, I fixed the errors but I don't know why the browser is not open.

I have: selenium Chrome Selenium Firefox

Console: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 23320) exited with code 0. To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops. Press any key to close this window . . .

Output: 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.25\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Users\Ariana\OneDrive\Desktop\AutomationPractice\AutomationPractice\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\AutomationPractice.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.25\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled. The program '[8276]

Hooks class:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestingProjectWebsite.StepDefinitions;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Description;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace TestingProjectWebsite
{

    public enum BrowserType
    {
        Chrome,
        Firefox
    }

    [TechTalk.SpecFlow.Binding]
    public class Hooks
    {
        private BrowserType _browserType;
        protected static IWebDriver Driver;

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void BeforeScenario()
        {
            var browserType = TestContext.Parameters.Get("Browser", "Chrome");
            _browserType = (BrowserType)Enum.Parse(typeof(BrowserType), browserType);
            if (Driver is null)
            {
                ChooseDriverInstance(_browserType);
                Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            }

            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");

        }

        public void ChooseDriverInstance(BrowserType browserType)
        {
            switch (browserType)
            {
                case BrowserType.Chrome:
                    Driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
                case BrowserType.Firefox:
                    Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
            }
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            if (!(Driver is null))
            {
                Driver.Quit();
                Driver = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is strange, in Tes Explorer, my tests are not displayed[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the test code in debug mode and place the breakpoint at the line where you're initializing the driver.
Chances are that your code is not even going inside the case statement you want it to go.

Comment: I tried to do that, but what is strange in Test Explorer, the tests are not displayed. I added an image in the description

Comment: @UtiAnm do you have SpecRun.SpecFlow as a dependency of your test project? Or alternatively, are you using another test runner like NUnit or xUnit? It doesn't look like the construct of your tests is correct to get them to appear in Visual Studio's test explorer